# File is not opening

Tags: asp.net, upload

I have a grid in which file names are displayed as link buttons. But when I click on link button, file does not open. Please see the cs file code method to open file.

```
protected void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        string fileName = btn.Attributes["FileName"].ToString();

        string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Files\\" + fileName;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            string type = "Application/word";
            if (type != "")
                Response.ContentType = type;
            Response.WriteFile(path);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
        }

        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@path);
        //Response.Write(path);   
    }
```

Here is the code of Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvMainList" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dtsFilesUploaded" 
                                                AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="Id, FileName" 
                                                onrowdatabound="gdvMainList_RowDataBound">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <ucc:CommandFieldControl HeaderText="Actions" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image"
                                                        DeleteImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/delete.png" ShowEditButton="true"
                                                        EditImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/edit.png" ShowCancelButton="true" CancelImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/cancel.png"
                                                        UpdateImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/update.png" DeleteConfirmationText="Are you sure you want to delete?">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="60px" />
                                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </ucc:CommandFieldControl>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>' OnClick="OpenFile" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uploaded On">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedDateTime","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblglCategoryId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("glCategoryId") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlglCategoryId" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" DataSourceID="dtsglCategoryId"
                                                                DataTextField="LookupItem" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="true" />
                                                </Columns>
                                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                    <div class="divEmptyListingGrid">
                                                        --- No Files Exists ---
                                                    </div>
                                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            </asp:GridView>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You can try puttin a breakpoint on the "string path ="... line and see that the variable path gets the correct path to the file.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an exception? Is `OpenFile` even executed?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: path has a value. I checked it.
@Daniel Hilgarth: No exception occurs. But my aspx code is in update pane;. Is it the problem?

Comment: You can use Firefox + Firebug to see if any errors are returned from the server during the AJAX call.

Comment: btw: Did you try copying the path and pasting it into windows explorer? Happens to me that I miss a character or something. Just to make sure.

Comment: Path is correct I'm sure.. Previously my files were not uploading and the problem was that I used the update panel. I resolved that problem somehow after searching a lot. Now this problem ... :(

Comment: actually it is the problem that my code is in update panel. When I remove update panel then it works fine. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response context will not be available inside update panel.

An alternative can be found here : http://forums.asp.net/p/1030846/1414305.aspx

Comment: What can I do for that? Please help. Exactly that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks .. But I have a problem. I have a link button and I want the same to that.

I wrote this in my aspx file <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFileUploadSave" />

But this gives an exception that there is no such control in my update panel.

Please help me regarding this. What can I do??????

Comment: Try this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx